# Shiny.io cannot deploy the application

Tags: r, shiny

I was trying to create an interactive map with the Shiny web application, however, after I published it to my shiny.io account, clicking the URL will only yield:
[shiny.io application page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNtCH.png)

```
An error has occurred!

An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
```

Can you help me with it? Thanks!

Here are the logs of the application:

```
2020-07-28T20:32:42.887039+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: jsonlite version: 1.6.1
2020-07-28T20:32:42.887039+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2020-07-28T20:32:42.887050+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: htmltools version: 0.5.0
2020-07-28T20:32:42.887235+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc2
2020-07-28T20:32:43.039412+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-28T20:32:43.039413+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Starting R with process ID: '58'
2020-07-28T20:32:43.106062+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:36754
2020-07-28T20:32:43.106061+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-28T20:32:43.035592+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2020-07-28T20:32:43.299242+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Warning: Error in plotlyOutput: could not find function "plotlyOutput"
2020-07-28T20:32:43.304719+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]:    99: div
2020-07-28T20:32:43.304717+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]:   100: dots_list
2020-07-28T20:32:43.304719+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]:    98: tabPanel
2020-07-28T20:53:57.079846+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Running on host: 220810008dc5
2020-07-28T20:53:57.085768+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Server version: 1.8.4-11
2020-07-28T20:53:57.085785+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8
2020-07-28T20:53:57.085827+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: R version: 4.0.0
2020-07-28T20:53:57.085867+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: shiny version: 1.5.0
2020-07-28T20:53:57.085869+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: httpuv version: 1.5.4
2020-07-28T20:53:57.085881+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: rmarkdown version: (none)
2020-07-28T20:53:57.085882+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: knitr version: (none)
2020-07-28T20:53:57.085895+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: jsonlite version: 1.6.1
2020-07-28T20:53:57.085909+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2020-07-28T20:53:57.085959+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: htmltools version: 0.5.0
2020-07-28T20:53:57.086171+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc2
2020-07-28T20:53:57.244930+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2020-07-28T20:53:57.248899+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-28T20:53:57.248900+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Starting R with process ID: '24'
2020-07-28T20:53:57.319981+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-28T20:53:57.319982+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:44567
2020-07-28T20:56:14.943220+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Running on host: 220810008dc5
2020-07-28T20:56:14.950036+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Server version: 1.8.4-11
2020-07-28T20:56:14.950099+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: httpuv version: 1.5.4
2020-07-28T20:56:14.950046+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8
2020-07-28T20:56:14.950063+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: R version: 4.0.0
2020-07-28T20:56:14.950165+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: knitr version: (none)
2020-07-28T20:56:14.950089+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: shiny version: 1.5.0
2020-07-28T20:56:14.950105+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: rmarkdown version: (none)
2020-07-28T20:56:14.950182+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: jsonlite version: 1.6.1
2020-07-28T20:56:14.950410+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc2
2020-07-28T20:56:15.113622+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2020-07-28T20:56:14.950182+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2020-07-28T20:56:14.950183+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: htmltools version: 0.5.0
2020-07-28T20:56:15.118668+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Starting R with process ID: '73'
2020-07-28T20:56:15.118666+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-28T20:56:15.192554+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: 
2020-07-28T20:56:15.192556+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:37222
2020-07-28T20:56:15.320813+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]: Warning: Error in plotlyOutput: could not find function "plotlyOutput"
2020-07-28T20:56:15.326689+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]:   100: dots_list
2020-07-28T20:56:15.326691+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]:    99: div
2020-07-28T20:56:15.326692+00:00 shinyapps[2621249]:    98: tabPanel
```

It worked perfectly in RStudio with the following ui.R and Server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("JHU COVID-19 Modeling Visualization Map"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            checkboxGroupInput("statesInput", "Choose the State(s)", 
                               c("AL", "MO", "AK", "MT", "AZ", "NE", 
                                 "AR", "NV", "CA", "NH", "CO", "NJ", 
                                 "CT", "NM", "DE", "NY", "DC", "NC", 
                                 "FL", "ND", "GA", "OH", "HI", "OK", 
                                 "ID", "OR", "IL", "PA", "IN", "RI", 
                                 "IA", "SC", "KS", "SD", "KY", "TN", 
                                 "LA", "TX", "ME", "UT", "MD", "VT", 
                                 "MA", "VA", "MI", "WA", "MN", "WV", 
                                 "MS", "WI", "WY"),
                               inline = TRUE),
                                                                       
            submitButton("Submit"),
                ), 

        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                        tabPanel("County Level", plotlyOutput("countyPolygonMap")), 
                        tabPanel("State Level", leafletOutput("statePolygonMap"))
            )
        )
)))
```

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(magrittr)
library(rgdal)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    library(rjson)
    library(plotly)
    library(dplyr)
    
    statepolygonZip <- download.file("https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip", 
                                     destfile = "cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip");
    unzip("cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip");
    statePolygonData <- readOGR("cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp", layer = "cb_2018_us_state_500k", 
                                GDAL1_integer64_policy = TRUE);
    ## obtaning the state shape file data provided by cencus.gov 
    ## for more categories of region shape file: 
    ## https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html
    
    
    output$countyPolygonMap <- renderPlotly({
        url <- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json'
        countyGeo <- rjson::fromJSON(file=url)
        ## Obtaining the geographical file for all U.S. counties
        url2<- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv"
        df <- read.csv(url2, colClasses=c(fips="character"))
        names(df)[2] = "unemployment"
        ## obtaining the unemployment rate data 
        url3 <- "https://storage.googleapis.com/kagglesdsdata/datasets%2F579969%2F1374720%2Fus_county.csv?GoogleAccessId=gcp-kaggle-com@kaggle-161607.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1596139521&Signature=easqHBFZ757D%2F7LVyDM%2BF%2FIMU6l2OEY6giqVvIC0l0tSSe%2Fohq6NC%2FLFKbsIV6FdFALmPUqG9vATbg0cuRVVwGQMsoUOjlW%2BZLhTVluxbYh1dDE1MTFzWRpzlSH18ejIwqa61F0ARJ%2Bpq6ryIfJuE7wQQ1rOCEpaVB9m%2FP7QaZm2gBJeHYLXJXcvO8w1p0sEnqRsGAesg2Fgj%2Bv8unPGNtDJekEWuNbl1K9k7CAaZWjG2QQ94LB9tAPvfKqykDWDD7w6yN3YFkcfu7kUmjs0CybnMD6IP%2FM5hvJXuUTIie0MOMTWt5bIua4qcTHxIxR5l918y1H17JA2HHrnKLVY%2BA%3D%3D"
        county <- read.csv(url3)
        county$nfips <- sprintf("%05d",county$fips)

        countyPolygonMap <- plot_ly() %>% add_trace(
            type="choroplethmapbox",
            geojson=countyGeo,
            locations=county$nfips,
            z=~county$population,
            colorscale="Viridis",
            zmin=200,
            zmax=1100000,
            marker=list(line=list(width=0),opacity=0.5)
        ) %>% layout(
            mapbox=list(
                style="carto-positron",
                zoom =2,
                center=list(lon= -95.71, lat=37.09))
        );
        countyPolygonMap;
        ## generating the interactive plotly map
    })
    
    output$statePolygonMap <-renderLeaflet ({
        statesAbbr <- subset(statePolygonData, input$statesInput %in% statePolygonData$STUSPS);
        ## subsetting the shape file with the selected states
        
        leaflet(statesAbbr) %>%
            addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
                        opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
                        fillColor = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", ALAND)(ALAND),
                        highlightOptions = highlightOptions
                        (color = "white", weight = 2,bringToFront = TRUE))
    })
    ## producing the map with polygon boundary on the state level
})
```

Comment: Do you have `library(plotlyOutput)` somewhere in your code to load the package?

Comment: Try moving `library()` statements out of the body of the server.  I am guessing it is checking the UI functions before it runs the server function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you verify you have `plotly` installed for this app, also check your `plotlyOutput` function in your app, which is where your application threw an error

`library(plotly)`

Comment: Nod. Make sure you have the library(plotly) statement in the file you deployed.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking you mean shinyapps.io.  To get to the logs:

1. Click on the dashboard view (the left-side panel).
2. Click on the name of your app (a hyperlink)
3. Click on the logs button at the top of the screen